# OpenGL Texture Swapping

Tags: opengl

I have 4 texture handles created with glGenTextures(). Throughout the lifecycle of my application I am replacing the pixels associated with these handles via glTexImage2d(). Is there a formal way to 'replace' the pixels associated with a texture? Do I have to call glDeleteTextures() everytime?

Comment: `glTexImage2D` will completely recreate the actual texture storage for this object, `glSubTexImage2D` allows you to replace (parts of ) the content, you could also render to it, blit to it, or write to it via image load/store. What;s the best option depends on what you actually try to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You can call [`glTexImage2D()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) again if you want to replace the entire texture or [`glTexSubImage2D()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml) if you want to replace a subset.

Or bind your texture to an FBO as a color attachment and render into some/all of it.